# Is it possible to display watch sensor data on phone without installing app on watch

Tags: java, android, wear-os

Display watch sensor data on phone without installing an app on watch?

How create an app that displays all the sensor data from watch?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible at the moment. The data collected such as heart rate is only available on the watch, so you must run an app there, collect and send to your mobile app.

See the samples for how to write an app for Wear OS.  https://github.com/android/health-samples/tree/main/health-services

And documentation https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services